# What would be an appropriate Stack site to ask questions about computer architecture?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Specifically, I am studying basic architecture as taught in a Comp. Org. class.  I have a question about multiplexors.

I have a problem on an assignment which states to draw a block diagram for a 7-word MUX and determine how many control switches it should have.  I'm not exactly sure what the problem means by "7-Word."  My interpretation is that there are 7-inputs and thus there should be 3 control switches (the way to find the number of control switches is to take `ceil(log_2(n))` and that the diagram would look like this:

```
  ctrl1      ctrl2   ctrl3
     |        |       |
   -----------------------
   |                     |
 A-|      7-input MUX    |
 B-|                     |---OUT
 C-|                     |
 D-|                     |
 E-|                     |
 F-|                     |
 G-|                     |
   -----------------------
```

I just want to be sure my interpretation is correct.  Am I right to assume 7 "word" mux is the same as 7 "input" mux?

Comment: Is this all the information you have?  What is the textbook?  What kind of class is this? (I can't imagine this being a question in a basic computing class, and if it is, it would deal with bits, not words).

Comment: This is an undergraduate junior level course in computer organization (we covered binary, hex, signed/unsigned ints, floating point, IA32 ATT assembly, Y86 ISA, boolean algebra, logic gates, and now this stuff)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.johnloomis.org/ece314/notes/carch/node5.html#SECTION00510000000000000000

Comment: Thanks, I will check out that site now.  I also posted my question on stack EE.

Comment: see also: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Stack Exchange site that is best suited for this particular question is [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).